# After publishing all code, getting ERR_UNSAFE_PORT on Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, iis, publish

I published my project's code on development server. Before publishing it, I created a website on IIS it's link 192.168.1.133:601 (localhost)

But on chrome get ERR_UNSAFE_PORT error.

Tried Explorer and Edge browser therefore it works.

Actual Result: On chrome get ERR_UNSAFE_PORT
Expected Result: Website works.

Answer (score 18):

After my long researches, I found some port list this is restircted by Google.

Thus, I realized that, my port in the list then I changed the port.

Link is https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/master/net/base/port_util.cc

Comment: You could also allow 601 port by adding  --explicitly-allowed-port in target parameter. Since we are not able to force all client user to change their chrome configuration. Use a safety port number would be the best workaround to fix this.

Comment: opening the list... please don't be there please don't be there, and my port is there... from aaaaaaaall the possible numbers I could pick I picked one of the black-list. Awesome...

Answer (score 0):

In July 2021, I encountered this problem and most of the standard fixes had already become obsolete (especially the one where you open 'Chrome Properties', since I use a Macbook.)

This is a MacOS-specific workaround, and here are the steps:

First, locate the Chrome icon in your 'Applications' folder, then right-click to select 'Show Package Content'. Double-click, to enter into the sub-folder. Select 'MacOS'. Inside, you'll see the Google Chrome executable. Rename it 'portfix', then open up a terminal.

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/portfix --explicitly-allowed-ports={port_you_want_unblocked}`

Don't forget to undo all of this when you're done with your tests, as this is a vulnerable way to leave your browser for too long!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used Port 87 and got the error ERR_UNSAFE_PORT.
After changing the Port the site is working...